# Rollup commonjs

Tags: angular, commonjs, aot, rollupjs

I am working on an Angular2 project. I went through Angular2 aot documents and I was able to generate ngFactory files. I used rollup js as suggested  in the docs. I have some non-es6 npm packages. I have used require to load the non-es6 packages.

The documentation(angular2 and rollup) suggests to make use of the rollup-plugin-commonjs for bundling the non-es6 modules. Following is my rollup configuration.

```js
export default {
    entry: 'scripts/main.js',
    dest: 'build/app.js', // output a single application bundle
    sourceMap: true,
    format: 'iife',
    context: 'this',
    plugins: [

        nodeResolve(
            {
                jsnext: true,
                module: true,
            }
        ),
        commonjs({
            include: 'node_modules/**/**',
        })  ,

        uglify()
    ]
}
```

I have the commonjs plugin in place. But still the browser errors as 'require  is undefined'. How can i achive bundling the non-es6 modules without the help of **webpack/ browserify** Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The setup I am currently using splits vendor/app files into seperate bundles. I haven't looked into getting this 
to work with AoT yet, which might be a problem, but I do have commonjs modules which are working with this method.

It did speed up development to only create my app bundle to test (I had issues with Webpack and 20s build times).

In a vendor.ts file (mine is in the same dir as the main.ts file) I have something like the following:

```
import * as _leaflet from 'leaflet/dist/leaflet'; //leaflet is installed via npm in this case.
...
export default {
    ...
    _leaflet
};
```

And a vendor.rollup.js file which uses the commonjs plugin like:

```
commonjs({
    include: [
        helpers.root('node_modules', '**') //This is just a method to make an absolute path to node_modules. See Angular 2 webpack docs for that.
    ]
})
```

Which creates a vendor bundle.

Then in my app.rollup.js (config file to create my app bundle).

```
export default {
    entry: 'src/main.ts',
    dest: 'bundles/app.js',
    format: 'iife',
    sourceMap: true,
    moduleName: 'app',
    plugins: [
        ...
    ],
    external: [
        'leaflet/leaflet'  //Yeah, you can rename it to have nicer looking imports.
    ],
    globals: {
        ...
        'leaflet/leaflet': 'vendor._leaflet'  //And map it to the correct global var here.
    }
};
```

And finally in my application I can use

`import * as L from 'leaflet/leaflet';`

Reminder: I haven't tried this with AoT compilation or production code yet, one step at a time.